# How do I comment in CoffeeScript? "/* this */" doesn't work

Tags: coffeescript, code-formatting, comments, block-comments

In what ways can you comment in CoffeeScript?

The documentation say you can use three hash symbols to start and close a comment block:

```
###
  Comments
  go
  here
###
```

I've found that I can sometimes use the following two formats

```
`// backticks allow for straight-JavaScript,
 // but the closing backtick can't be on a comment line (I think?)
`
```

Are there a simpler way to insert short comments in CoffeeScript?

Do NOT use this style**

Since this is getting a lot of views, I want to emphasize that

```
/* Comment goes here */
```

produces a MATH error when the `/*` is on its own line.

As Trevor pointed out in a comment on the question, this is a **regular expression**, **NOT** a comment!

Comment: If a `/*...*/` comment "works," it's because the CoffeeScript compiler is interpreting it as a regex. Definitely not recommended!

Comment: So I guess there is NO WAY in CoffeeScript to have an intra-statement (between characters) comment?

Comment: Since I'm limited in formatting comments, I'll post an answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Use a single # sign

```
# like this
```

One character seems pretty minimal ;)

Also:

```
###
This block comment (useful for ©-Copyright info) also gets 
passed on to the browsers HTML /* like this! */
###
```

Comment: This is usually how you will want to comment; the triple hash is most often used when you want the comment to fall through to the javascript (copyright messages, usually).

Comment: Ah *sigh*. The official docs use the single # form all through their examples, but never actually mention it in the text explanations, it only talks about the block comments.

Comment: Unfortunately no way to have block comments that don't show up in output.

Answer (score 24):

The main way to comment is sh/Perl/Ruby/... style `#` comments:

```
# This comment goes to the end of the line
# and it won't appear in the "compiled"
# JavaScript version.
```

You use the [block style `###` comments](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#strings) when you want a comment to appear in the JavaScript version:

> Sometimes you'd like to pass a block comment through to the generated JavaScript. For example, when you need to embed a licensing header at the top of a file. Block comments, which mirror the syntax for heredocs, are preserved in the generated code.

So if you start with

```
###
PancakeParser is Public Domain
###
```

then you'd get this JavaScript comment in the generated JavaScript:

```
/*
PancakeParser is Public Domain
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

Beware of ###! If you use ### to separate sections of code (as I do) it's awfully surprising when that code stops working as a result.

Comment: Do you know why? We have the code working locally but not on the build server with ###.

Comment: Unfortunately, I noticed this months ago, and I'm not "in that space" right now to have a look at it.

Comment: Because a pair makes a block comment?

Comment: Would not be so surprising if you used a syntax-highlighting editor, with comments appearing in a different color

Comment: Why downvote?  It's a valid warning.  Really, it's saying don't use a solid line of # as a section separator, or you may occasionally get unbalanced block comment pairs.

Answer (score 1):

For comments in the middle of a line, try:

```
if somecond `/* hi */` && some other cond, etc.
```

The backticks cause CoffeeScript to put the enclosed text into the generated JavaScript as is.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CoffeeScript is inconsistent with whether comments introduced with a single # character make it to the output JavaScript. For example:

```
# testme.coffee

fName = 'John'
lName = 'Smith'
fullName = "#{fName} #{lName}" # |||| $:
if true #comment
    console.log `/* hi */` 'Hello, World!'
```

compiles to

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 2.7.0
(function() {
  // testme.coffee
  var fName, fullName, lName;

  fName = 'John';

  lName = 'Smith';

  fullName = `${fName} ${lName}`;

  if (true) { //comment
    console.log(/* hi */`Hello, World!`);
  }

}).call(this);
```

Note the missing comment on the line that assigns to fullName.