# Comments in Embedded Coffeescript (ECO) templates

Tags: coffeescript, eco

Is there a way to put comments (single and multiline) in [ECO templates](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) such that they do not appear in the rendered output?

For example, Django templates let you do this on a [single line](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#comments):

```
{# greeting #}hello
```

or on [multiple lines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-comment):

```
<p>Rendered text with {{ pub_date|date:"c" }}</p>
{% comment %}
    <p>Commented out text with {{ create_date|date:"c" }}</p>
{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively everything inside the `<% %>` is coffeescript (ECO = Embedded CoffeeScript). Comments in CoffeeScript use the `#` character to comment a single line (and `###` for multiline comments). See [coffeescript - How to comment? "/* this */" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781685/coffeescript-how-to-comment-this-doesnt-work)

So in ECO you would comment like this:

```
<% #This is a single line comment %>
```

If you examine the source code for [ECO templates](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) you can see the regex that's handling the comment situation in [scanner.js](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco/blob/master/lib/scanner.js).

```
Scanner.modePatterns = {
      data: /(.*?)(<%%|<%\s*(\#)|<%(([=-])?)|\n|$)/,
      code: /(.*?)((((:|(->|=>))\s*))?%>|\n|$)/,
      comment: /(.*?)(%>|\n|$)/
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a special tag for commenting, namely, `<%# %>`

Example:

```
<%# This is a single line comment %>
```