# Is it possible to put a hash in a coffeescript comment

Tags: coffeescript, comments

I want to create a comment in coffeescript that transpiles to the following js:

```
//# This is a comment with an hash
```

The # in the comment is necessary because of a framework build script (qooxdoo) that uses the hashed comment as a directive. And of course that is a bit tricky as the # is used to demarcate a comment.

How can a put a hash (#) in a coffeescript comment such that the # is transpiled to javascript in a comment?

Comment: @mu is too short. I don't think that this question already has been answered. Please read both my question and answer and compare this with the so-called duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781685/coffeescript-how-to-comment-this-doesnt-work.

Comment: But the answers cover the same material: "how do CoffeeScript comments work?"

Comment: But maybe I was a little quick with the Golden Hammer of Closing.

Comment: @muistooshort. It's a bit of a detail, I know, but just in case anyone else wants to use a hash in a coffeescript comment.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
###*
# #This is a comment with a hash
###
```

At least within a block comment this transpiles to:

```
/**
 * #This is a comment with a hash
 */
```

Comment: Only `###` comments actually get through to the JavaScript so AFAIK the problem isn't that you have `#` inside a CoffeeScript comment, the problem is that CoffeeScript removes (most) comments along the way. You could use backticks to embed a raw JavaScript comment too but that would be nasty.